# Combine list of types with generics

Tags: typescript

Is there some easier way to iterate with generic and build combined types around those?

Currently this is working ok, but requires tons of maintenance like in this example for AllStoreData type and AllInstaceData type when there is 40+ IRegistedDemoTypes, and 6 set of combined types.

Just having `Demo1 | Demo2` won't work as then it merges those as one for type.

```js
export interface IRegisterDemoType<TaskType extends string = string, TaskProps = unknown> {
    key: TaskType;
    props: TaskProps;
}

type Demo1 = IRegisterDemoType<'demo1', {
    value: string;
    another: number;
}>;

type Demo2 = IRegisterDemoType<'demo2', undefined>;

interface StoreData<Type extends IRegisterDemoType> {
    storeKey: Type['key'];
    storeProps: Type['props'];
}

interface InstanceData<Type extends IRegisterDemoType> {
    instanceKey: Type['key'];
    instanceProps: Type['props'];
}

type AllStoreData = StoreData<Demo1> | StoreData<Demo2>;
type AllInstanceData = InstanceData<Demo1> | InstanceData<Demo2>;

function handleStore(data: AllStoreData) {
    switch (data.storeKey) {
        case 'demo1': {
            console.log(data.storeProps);
            // storeProps have valid type
        }
    }
}

function handleInstance(data: AllInstanceData) {
    switch (data.instanceKey) {
        case 'demo1': {
            console.log(data.instanceProps);
            // instanceProps have valid type
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
type AllDemos = [Demo1, Demo2];
type StoreBuilder<T extends IRegisterDemoType[]> = {
    [Property in keyof T]: StoreData<T[Property]>;
};

type AllStoreData = StoreBuilder<AllDemos>[number];
```

... except this fails on build time

```js
error TS2344: Type 'T[Property]' does not satisfy the constraint 'IRegisterDemoType<string, unknown>'.
  Type 'T[keyof T]' is not assignable to type 'IRegisterDemoType<string, unknown>'.
    Type 'T[string] | T[number] | T[symbol]' is not assignable to type 'IRegisterDemoType<string, unknown>'.
      Type 'T[string]' is not assignable to type 'IRegisterDemoType<string, unknown>'.

29  [Property in keyof T]: StoreData<T[Property]>;
```

Comment: seems that requires TS 4.7.4 or newer to work

Comment: Is this meant to be an answer or more of the question, given that you're saying it fails... or maybe doesn't fail, depending on version?  And this mostly looks like a code-only answer; could you explain what you're doing and why it works (*if* it works)?